# razor page redirect after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have a task running i the background generating and image.
When i have the image placed on the server, I want to go to a page that shows the image.

I am having trouble doing that, I expect due to lack of knowledge of razor pages in asp.net core v. 2.0

Basically I have my page:

```
<div>
    <img src="images/IAmGeneratingAnImage.png"/>
</div>
```

And my model:

```
class xx:PageModel ...

    public void OnGet() {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { CheckForImageAndRedirect(); });
    }

    private void CheckForImageAndRedirect() {
        string fileNameFull = "";
        do
        {
            var file = new FileInfo("C:\...\imageName.png");
            if (file.Exists )) 
                fileNameFull = file.FullName;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNameFull));   

        RedirectToPage("OtherPageThatDisplaysImage"); // razorpage also.
    }
```

I would really like to pass the path to the new page as well, that can probably also be done...

So those are my two questions:
 a) how do I redirect to a page after a task is completed ?
 b) how do I pass the new imagepath to the new page ?

Or am I attaching the problem completely wrong?

Comment: Response.Redirect("OtherPageThatDisplaysImage"); // is my guess now... (after asking the question)

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is in the use of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Not only is that a bad thing to do, in general, in a web application, but when you do that, the code that's being run is taken off to a new thread. That's sort of the point, but the result of that is that your application moves on, and when your method finally wants to redirect, there's nothing left to redirect: the response has either already been returned or is too far along to change it. More to the point, the code running here now doesn't even have access to the response to change it if it could, because it's not running in the same thread context.

If you want to do something "in the background", you need to offload it to an actual background *process*, not a new thread. You can use HangFire or similar tools to accomplish this. You then move on and return the response to the user, and either use SignalR or long-poll via AJAX to check on the status of your background job. Once your job is completed, then you can redirect the user appropriately, but that will need to happen *client-side*, not server-side. Once the server has returned a response, it's done. It has no ability to issue a redirect without first receiving a new request from the client.

Lastly, while not pertinent to the issue at hand here, be advised that `Thread.Sleep` is blocking. You should use `Task.Sleep` instead.

Comment: thanks.. hmm client side check could be done simply by polling in javascript.. (and thanks for the sleep)